# JPA with dynamic datasource and CMT

Tags: jpa, dynamic, transactions, datasource, commit

I am using Java EE 6, JPA 2, JBoss 7.1.1 and EJB 3.1.

In my application I only know on request time (EJB method call) which datasource is meant. In the examples the there are static entries in the persistence.xml. So I created the EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager by my own. Unfortunately JBoss does not know the EntityManager and the commit is not done by the server (no CMT). If I let inject the EntityManager all works fine, but the I have no dynamic datasource.

My question: is there a way to have dynamic/request-time datasources and CMT? Probably tell JBoss about the self instantiated EntityManager?

I got really stuck and I think I have to switch to BMT, but I hope not?